# Crystal Report (XI RDP) is holding on to Access Database

Tags: ms-access, vb6, crystal-reports, .net

Our VB6 application works with multiple MS-Access databases which represent different resultsets. When the user selects a resultset, the database  that contains the resultset is renamed to Temp.mdb for the time the user needs its data. When the user is done the Temp.mdb is renamed to its original name. (Please accept this design, there was a good reason for it at the time).

A pitfall of this design is, that when there is an open connection to the Temp.mdb the rename fails with a permission denied error. So in our code all connections are meticulously closed beforehand.

Enter Crystal reports:
We create a report using CraxDRT.Application.OpenReport(path), pass it around some Net dll's to set its parameters and then send it to the CRViewer or the printer. After this it seems that the report keeps lingering around and keeps an open connection the the Temp.mdb, thereby write protecting the temp.ldb. I tried to set all references tot the report within Vb6 and Net to null/Nothing, but the report itself has no IDispose interface, Close method or whatever. Only when I close the main application the connection to the database disappears. After restarting I can then rename it.

There must be a way to release the lock that the report holds on the Temp.ldb file so that I can rename the Temp.mdb. But how??

PS: The strange thing is that when I call up a different report that uses the same data, but that is not passed to Net dll's, in some way or another the lingering report is garbage collected and it releases its lock too.

Comment: What logic is driving the report's data source? Are you opening any recordsets? Is there a Close method somewhere that you need to include in your code? You might try using NirSofts OpenedFilesView to see what's actually holding the database open: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/opened_files_view.html

Comment: @HK1 The reports has its own queries that it executes on the the databases using a system DSN. If only there was a Report.Close, Report.Dispose etc method, but there is not.

Comment: Probably a dumb question but is it possible or feasible for you to control the reports data source so that you could close the connection? (I speak in ignorance, I've never used Crystal Reports).

Comment: @HK1 Well yes, if someone can tell me how to forcibly close all connections to the database using DAO I am home free.

Comment: "... forcibly close all connections to the database using DAO" I suppose you mean from the "outside" so to speak? I'm not aware that that's possible without having a reference to the connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not garbage collection issue then it's probably connection pooling by .NET/OLEDB provider CR is using. Though usually it is not enabled for JET databases.

You can wrap your reporting logic in a separate executable that launches CR viewer or prints report and then exits effectively forcing GC and/or clearing open connections.

Comment: This probably is the right approach, but I find it too cumbersome. I reverted some of the code that was ported to Net in such a way that no reference to the databases is carried to it. We will see what happens when we migrate the entire Crystal Reports code from VB6 to Net.